# Apache + Nginx reverse proxy not serving index.php by default

Tags: apache, nginx, fastcgi, reverse-proxy

I have a bunch of sites that work great with nginx + php-fastcgi and I have no complaints there! The only thing that doesn't work is a PHP gallery application called Gallery3. Sadly, I have to use Apache with this application. The problem I have is as follows:

gallery.wfto.cc -- Doesn't work (downloads an unnamed file containing the PHP code of index.php because it isn't getting parsed)

gallery.wfto.cc/ -- Doesn't work (same thing)

gallery.wfto.cc/index.php -- Doesn't work (same thing)

gallery.wfto.cc/index.php/ -- Works.

gallery.wfto.cc:9001 (all variants) -- Works.

I have no idea what is going on. I included most of my configurations below. The /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf is a ... general proxy configuration, nothing special.

```
##NGINX CONFIG##
server {
    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
    listen [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/vhosts/wfto.cc/subdomains/gallery;

    server_name gallery.wfto.cc;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/gallery.wfto.cc.access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
    }
}
## APACHE CONFIG ##
<VirtualHost *:9001>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/wfto.cc/subdomains/gallery
        <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
                AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
                Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
                Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
                FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header Authorization
        </IfModule>
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/wfto.cc/subdomains/gallery/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the nginx server entry is actually used and not some other by accident (e.g. mis-spelled the domain name in the URL)? Check the access log to make sure. Some more dumb things to check: restart nginx making sure no running process is alive after stopping; change `root` to an empty directory (if it's proxying everything to Apache then nginx doesn't need access to the content).

Comment: I changed root to point to a null directory (empty directory) but that doesn't change anything.  That server block is the only one catching the traffic on that subdomain.

Comment: After changing to an empty directory have you checked Apache's access log whether or not your test actually gets through to Apache at all? If you still get "the same result" (I assume a download of the content of index.php) then this could also mean your browser is simply returning a cached result.

Comment: .... It was the browser.  I had, at one point, cleared Chrome's cache but I should have done it each time.

Comment: Note that as of 2020, Gallery3 has full support for `nginx`; see my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know at what point things started working, but if you're changing server configurations make sure you clear your browser's cache completely.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in apache conf:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I don't think it has to do with DirectoryIndex because when I access Apache directly via gallery.wfto.cc:9001, it works fine.

Comment: Add to "location /" in nginx following line:
            
index  index.php;

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient thread, but because [Gallery3 has gone through a revival](https://galleryrevival.com/), it might be worth adding another, more up-to-date answer, for those who have googled for a solution and found your question here.

The following solution by [@jonmiller](https://github.com/jonmiller) works: http://jonamiller.com/2015/02/15/gallery3-on-nginx/

Because the Internet is fickle, and sites come and go (his blog only has two entries from 2015, clearly something he has not been updating...), taking into account that all credits are due to Jon Miller, here is the working configuration:

```php
server {
    server_name <gallery_url>;
    listen 80;

    root <path_to_gallery_installion>;

    access_log <path_to_log_locations>;
    error_log <path_to_log_locations>;

    index index.php;

    location / {

        location ~ /(index\.php/)?(.+)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php?kohana_uri=$2&$args;
            location ~ /var/thumbs/.*/.album.jpg {
                # Direct access to album thumbs explicity allowed
            }
            location ~ /\.(ht|tpl(\.php?)|sql|inc\.php|db)$ {
                deny all;
            }
            location ~ /var/(uploads|tmp|logs) {
                deny all;
            }
            location ~ /bin {
                deny all;
            }
            location ~ /var/(albums|thumbs|resizes) {
                rewrite ^/var/(albums|thumbs|resizes)/(.*)$ /file_proxy/$2 last;
            }
            location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|ttf)$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php?kohana_uri=$uri&$args;
                expires 30d;
            }
        }

        location = /index.php {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_pass localhost:9000; // adjust as necessary
        }
    }
}
```

According to Jon Miller, the real trick that made all the above work correctly was to change one line on `application/config/config.php`:

```ini
$config["index_page"] = "";
```

**Disclaimer:** I have posted the above solution (with due credit to Jon Miller) as a feature request on the [official repository for Gallery the Revival on GitHub](https://github.com/bwdutton/gallery3/issues/8) for inclusion in the documentation (README.md, a separate file, whatever), since it's critical for Gallery3 admins to be aware that they now can get it working under `nginx` and (at least) PHP 7.4.